# Asymptotics of an integral

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals

Consider an integral
$$
   I(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i\xi x } \delta(\xi^2-k^2)\chi( (\xi-k,\gamma)) \, d\xi  
$$
where $x, k, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|\gamma| = 1$ and $(x,y)\equiv xy = x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n$. Here $\delta$ is the Dirac delta, $\chi$ is the Heaviside step function:
$$
   \chi(t) = 1_{\left\{ t \geqslant 0 \right\}}.
$$
How can I obtain asymptotics of such integral $I(x)$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Comment: You might wish to recall how you define $\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}u(\xi)\delta(\xi^2-k^2)\mathrm d\xi$, for every suitable function $u$ and every $k$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Didier It is an integral over sphere $\xi^2 = k^2$ of $u(\xi)$ (I think there are no additional multipliers, are they?).

Comment: You are looking for the characteristic function of the top half of the sphere ?  I think you can get it (semi) explicitly, with the technique that works for the whole sphere, as described concisely here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086905000034   full disclosure: haven't tried the calculation myself

Comment: @mike And if for an integral $\Omega(r)=\int\limits_{-1}^{1} e^{itr}(1-t^2)^{\frac{m-3}{2}} dt$ it is easy to compute asymptotics?

Comment: I think so, but I'm giving you another ignorant opinion.  If m is odd you have an integral you can do explicitly.  Someone else will know better that I do how to do the asymptotics.  I think this is an interesting question so I'm going to see if I can work it out, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: @mike It can be expressed via Bessel function! So now I'm thinking of what to do in general case (when $k$ and $\gamma$ aren't oppositely directed and the integral is not over the whole sphere).